# Saving into 2 models with one form in Cakephp3

Tags: save

I have 2 models : Users and Vendors model with relation : Vendors belongsto Users and Users hasMany Vendors.

The users table have following data : 
[Users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDOLe.png)

The vendors have the following data : [Vendors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3PGZ.png)

The vendors table have a foreign key (user_id ) which is primary key in users table 
I am trying to do vendor register. With that the data will be saved in both tables , (probaly will be saved in vendor table first and then user table ) . Here's is my code in VendorsController.php :

public function add()
    {

```
    $vendor = $this->Vendors->Users->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $vendor = $this->Vendors->patchEntity($vendor, $this->request->data , ['associated' => ['Users']]);

        if ($this->Vendors->save($vendor)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The vendor has been saved.'));

           // return $this->redirect(['acbbtion' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The vendor could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
       return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'listings','action' => 'add']);
    }
    $users = $this->Vendors->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this -> set(compact('vendors','users'));

    $this->set('_serialize', ['vendor']);
```

However, this code is only save the data in vendors table but not user table.And user_id ( foreign key in vendors table will have value NULL) .  How can I make it to save in user table also ?